# PyOpenCL kernel parameters

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

According to the [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/runtime_program.html#pyopencl.Program.kernel_name) the `kernal_name` function needs 3 API params:

```
program.kernel_name(queue, shape, None, kernal-params...)
```

but it is not documented, what `None` and `shape` parameters are used for. As far as I understand, the third parameter is the kernel function itself and could be just `None`, but what is the second parameter `shape` used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the book "OpenCL in Action" the parameters are:

1. queue
2. global_size: tuple
3. local_size: tuple
4. *args: arguments to kernel
5. global_offset=None
6. wait_for=None

The kernel function is selected by the name of what you called kernel_name in your code.
E.g. if you have a kernel function named "__kernel void foo(...)", then just call program.foo(...) in Python.
The global_size specifies how many work-items are used and the local size specifies the size of a work-group. 
The parameters of the kernel are passed in the order they appear in the kernel function, which is denoted by *args.

Here is an example from the mentioned book: 
`program.mult(queue, (25,), (25,), scalar, float_buffer, lm)`.
From the program, the kernel with name "mult" is created, global and local size is set to 25, i.e. it is a 1D task, and the arguments scalar (of type numpy.float32), float_buffer (of type cl.Buffer) and lm (of type cl.LocalMemory) are passed to the kernel. 
The corresponding kernel is:
`__kernel void mult(float num, __global float *global_floats, __local float4 *local_floats) {...}`

You can, of course, also do it the way it is done in pure C. This needs more typing, but the advantage is that it is very clear to see what happens:

1. create kernel: cl.Kernel
2. set arguments: kernel.set_arg
3. enqueue task: cl.enqueue_nd_range_kernel

Comment: can you pleas explain why it is tuples for both global and local sizes?

Comment: with global size, you say how many work-items you want to have. It can be a 1d, 2d or 3d tuple, e.g. you want to change the brightness of a 320x240px image -> just use (320, 240) as global size.
With local size, you say how many work-items you want to put in a work-group, i.e. you partition your work-items. Items in a work-group can work together, e.g. they can share fast local memory. 
Because you partition your global size with your local size into groups, both must have the same dimension, e.g. g.s=(1,10) and l.s.=(1,2) gives 5 groups. If you don't care about work-groups, just put None.